# .NET Core: TcpClient.GetStream crashes when using async

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, async-await, .net-core

I tried to play with .NET Core and want to connect to a local TCP server. No issues when I do it synchronously (see first `Connect` method). When I try to do it with `async`/`await` (see second `ConnectAsync` method), it goes crazy and nearly undebuggable. I'm not sue if I use TcpClient correctly since there are not as many examples yet available on the web. The exact problems start after calling `TcpClient.GetStream`. I tried to debug into this with `JustMyCode` disabled and `All exceptions` checkbox in Visual Studio Code - but it just don't jumps into `TcpClient.GetStream`.

Observations in `async` mode:

- sometimes it crashes in `TcpClient.GetStream` directly
- sometimes it crashes after the the calling function returns (I saw the last `Console.WriteLine` appears in console sometimes)
- the program immediately stops, debugger shuts down (no exception thrown)
- return code is always zero (`The program 'bla' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000)`)

My system/project setup:

- Windows 10 64bit (Education)
- .NET Core 1.0.0
- Console application
- local TCP Server, therefore no connectivity issues
- Visual Studio Code (shouldn't matter)

Code:

```cs
public class Connection
{
    private TcpClient _client;
    public NetworkStream Stream { get; private set; }
    private CancellationTokenSource _token;

    public Connection()
    {
        _token = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _client = new TcpClient();
    }

    public void Connect(string host, int port)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connecting...");
        _client.ConnectAsync(host, port);
        Console.WriteLine("connected!");

        while (!_client.Connected)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("getting stream...");
        Stream = _client.GetStream(); // works because of Thread.Sleep above until the socket is connected
        Console.WriteLine("got stream!");
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connecting...");
        await _client.ConnectAsync(host, port);
        Console.WriteLine("connected!");

        // I know I could check for TcpClient.Connected but I see in debugger that the property is True

        Console.WriteLine("getting stream...");
        Stream = _client.GetStream(); // crash in GetStream / crash after this function has returned
        Console.WriteLine("got stream!"); // sometimes this is going to be printed, sometimes not
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Im puzzled by the connect (non async) version.. connect, while connected sleep, now try get stream..  You dont do that in the second one.. you just connect and expect to get the stream..

Comment: Do you call ConnectAsync only one time or multiple times on the same instance ?

Comment: Did you try to get the exception that is thrown? Maybe that gives a hint. Would be good if you could share this one.

Comment: @BugFinder, yes, as stated above I am sure I am connected because I had a look at the properties with the debugger.

Comment: @Guillaume, only one time, of course.

Comment: @Nitram, probably I didn't make that clear enough: there is no exception that I can catch! The program just exists with error code zero. Therefore I can't provide any details.

Comment: @TheWavelength That is exactly the one detail I needed. Writing a answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are describing points to the main thread of your application dying. To identify that problem correctly one has to look at the entire applications and the threads that are active at any given moment.

But for example a simple console application terminates as soon as the main sub is terminated. Depending on how you call your `ConnectAsync` function you may lack something that ensures that the main loop is not terminated. Make sure that your main entry point is not a `async` function because this will terminate as soon as it reaches it's first `await`.

The main difference that happens between your two methods is that the `ConnectAsync` method actually switches threads very likely and executes the second part in a different thread, not blocking the thread it was called in like the `Connect` function does.

It explains exactly the behaviour your are describing. Some time after the

```
await _client.ConnectAsync(host, port);
```

line is executed the main loop of your application terminates and causes the entire .NET VM to shut down.

Comment: Thank you a ton! Respect for getting this without even knowing how I call `ConnectAsync`. The solution was to simply let the entry point wait on the result of the function call that calls `ConnectAsync`.